# Export Range to New Excel Document VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA but working on some reports and it would be a lot simpler to create a macro button to auto export a defined range to a new .xlsx document.

I have so far:

```
Sub ExportTest()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1:K10")
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
    Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")
    WS.SaveAs "test", ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

I get error 1004, which seems to be an issue with the SaveAs part.

But cannot figure out how to auto save this to a pre-defined folder.
Also if possible would it be possible to reference the filename as a cell in the original workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the SaveAs syntax. Try this

```
WS.SaveAs "test", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Is there a way to define where the file saves to? ie 'C:\test\' also i would assume to automatically set the filename i could add a 'Set Filename = ("A1")' and change "test" to filename?

Comment: So i have figured out 'WS.SaveAs "C:\test\" & "\test", xlOpenXMLWorkbook' saves the file as test in c:\Test

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it now thank you!

```
Sub Test()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:K10")
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "C:\test\"
filename = Range("A1")
WS.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```